# Array of different objects to .CSV

Tags: javascript, csv

I am trying to do something simple, I want to push an array of objects to a .csv file, the problem Im having is that the objects are not all the same key. I am using this export-to-csv library but am not committed to it.

Here is what I am doing currently:

```
exportBudget() {
  this.tester()


  const options = { 
    fieldSeparator: ',',
    quoteStrings: '"',
    decimalSeparator: '.',
    showLabels: true, 
    showTitle: true,
    title: 'My Awesome CSV',
    useTextFile: false,
    useBom: true,
    useKeysAsHeaders: true,

  };

  const csvExporter = new ExportToCsv(options);
  csvExporter.generateCsv(this.test);
  },
```

and here is the tester() function:

```
    tester(){
  for(var i=0; i<this.rows.length;i++){
      var data = {Marketing: this.rows[i].toString(), Canada: this.records[i].details[0].value, USA: this.records[i].details[1].value, UK: this.records[i].details[2].value, Europe: this.records[i].details[3].value, Australia:this.records[i].details[4].value, RestofWorld:this.records[i].details[5].value}
      this.test.push(data);
      };
  for(var i=0; i<this.addSpend.length;i++){
    var data = {Marketing: this.addSpend[i].marketDet, Territory: this.addSpend[i].territory, Vendor: this.addSpend[i].vendor, Vendor_Description: this.addSpend[i].description, Amount: this.addSpend[i].amount, Date: this.addSpend[i].date}
    this.test.push(data);
      };
},
```

when I open this csv, I get the headers from the first for loop push ( ie Marketing, Canada, USA...etc) and the second loop push shows undefined in the csv. I can see this is because the Keys do not match up. What I want to see is something like this, but cannot seem to figure out how to add two 'tables':

[CSV Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y13bm.png)

Any help on how to accomplish this would be great, thank you!

Comment: The data doesn't really seem to be related to each other, why create only a single csv file for the output? If it needs to be one file, could you add all the columns in the first row?

Comment: @Icepickle Thanks for the response. It does need to be one csv, the data is related in a way. The point of this csv is for the user to output the data to share/manipulate. As for your second suggestion, I did try this (if I am understanding you correctly) and I set row 1  to be all the column headers. This did not work, for some reason when I push addSpend to test, it shows up "undefined' in the csv (if I did it alone it shows up fine though). Aside from that, the header would then be in row one and the data would be much further down, which is less then ideal.

Comment: Then you could disable showing the title, and add the headers yourself manually? Maybe just pushing raw array values instead of objects? Can you link in the `ExportToCsv` library you seem to be using, their might be some documentation in it?

Comment: @Icepickle yea I tried to manually put in the headers and creates the same issues. I will try to push the array alone. Here is the github repository; https://github.com/alexcaza/export-to-csv#readme

Comment: @Icepickle Hey, just wanted to let you know that pushing it as arrays "worked", it takes some semi-gross/bad syntax, but it'll work for my purposes. Thanks for the suggestion, I appreciate it!

Comment: thanks for the feedback, if you found a satisfying answer, you could answer your own question? Maybe it will be of some use for future questioners :)

Answer (score 0):

As @Icepickle suggested, pushing the data as an array rather then an array of objects gave more freedom to manipulate the data as I needed. All I ended up needing to do was:

```
     this.test.push([this.rows[i].toString(), this.records[i].details[0].value, this.records[i].details[1].value,  this.records[i].details[2].value,  this.records[i].details[3].value, this.records[i].details[4].value,this. records[i].details[5].value]);
```

So if your data is coming in the form of an array objects just parse into an array instead, now my data looks like this, as intended:
[image: Solution]